# dojo drag and drop how to drop to absolute position?

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop, dojo-dnd

I am trying to drag a div onto a target. When dropping the item I want to position it on the target at the position it was dropped.

I need to use dojo dnd. The problem i am having is finding the position where I have dropped the item so that I can update the dropped items position.

Where can I access the dropped position from?

I tried to subscribe to the dojo drop event:

```
            dojo.subscribe("/dnd/drop", function(a,b){

            var i = dojo.create("div",{
                style:"position:absolute; top:"+a._lastY+";left:"+a._lastX+"; height:20px; width:20px; background-color:blue;",
            });
            dojo.place(i, query("body")[0]);
        });
```

the only positions I could find were lastX and lastY.

Any help would be brilliant!

Thanks,

Comment: Cheers there is no /dnd/drag topic or event...?

Comment: here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/gFNS7/12/) that might help.